# script that checks if file.html exists and if so, run another script else die?

Tags: html, linux, email, scripting, cron

So i have a cron job that occaisonally produces a html file to a certain directory. It runs this process once an hour. Im after a script that i can run after this one to check for the existance of this file and if it exists, emails it to a email address (namely my phone) for monitoring purposes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing, im completely lost. I am new to linux scripting it was a fairly large achievement to get the first part working! Thanks.

Comment: Then why don't you start here: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ - especially look for section "Decision making in shell script ( i.e. if command)"

Comment: I'll have a look thanks. Sorry I didn't really know what I was searching for.

Answer (score 5):

One of the many ways would be to use `test`.

```
#!/bin/bash
test -f filename && script/command_to_be_executed
```

equivalent: `[]` => `test`

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -f filename ] && script/command_to_be_executed
```

The above line implies that if the `test` succeeds then perform the operation specified after `&&`, not otherwise. In this case, `-f` implies testing for file existence, if file by the name `filename` exits perform the operation specified succeeding `&&`
Replace `filename` with absolute path of the file (file.html) you want to check for, followed by command or script you want to run succeeding `&&`
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash script that might get you going in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/bash
FileYouWantToTest='/directory/filename.ext'
echo -n "Verifying if $FileYouWantToTest exist..."
if [ -f $FileYouWantToTest ]
    then
        echo  "OK"
    else
        echo  "FAIL"
fi
exit 0
```

copy the code, save it in a folder with .sh as the ending, and make sure it is executable... then run in the shell.. 
[Advanced Bash Scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)